# Regular expression: matching only if the latter sequence is not a specific letter

Tags: regex

I am trying to match the strings in the form of "${234}" but the ones that don't have a "=" character at the right side of it.

For example:

```
v1 = 345 + ${234};
```

Here ${234} should match. I can do this with \${([0-9]+)}

But the following shouldn't match:

```
${234} = 345 + v5;
```

Because there is a "=" at the right of the "${234}"sequence.

I know that there are some expressions to match for "sequences ending with". But as you see, it is a bit different here.

Is it possible to match the above sequence with regexp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead `(?!...)`:

```
\${([0-9]+)}(?!.*=)
```

This will only match if there *isn't* an `=` some point after the `${...}`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
(?:(\$\{\d\d\d\}) ?[^=])
```

This is essentially literal `$` followe by literal `{` followed by `3 digits` followed by literal `}` followed by optional space, **not** followed by =.

f.e.: only the ${234} will be captured as group.

test here: https://regexr.com/3jgqk